# Function returns empty file although contains content

Tags: php

I have a problem, I generate a preview of the page template and save the HTML to the `template.php` file. As long as the file `template.php` contains what it should contain, then when you click on the button, the generated file is empty - why?

I have two files - generate.php (containing the generation of the preview and the button in the next form to generate the download)

Get.php - script for downloading the file

**GENERATE.PHP**

```
<?php
    $template = ob_get_flush();
    $fp = fopen('template.html', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $template);
    fclose($fp);
    file_put_contents('template.html', $template);
?>


<form method="post" action="get.php">
    <div id="container">
        <input type="submit" id="download" value="Download template"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**GET.PHP**

```
<?php

    $download = file_get_contents('./template.html');
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=template.html');
    header('Content-length: '.strlen($download));

?>
```

Comment: Why in `generate.php` are you writing to the file twice?

Comment: what data your write on file

Comment: This line is for other PHP versions

Comment: @Bhargav HTML code generated by PHP

Comment: but wich  html code you explain briefly

Comment: Is your `template.html` file in the same directory as your `get.php` file?

Comment: @DrRoach of course

Comment: @Bhargav add the generated HTML code to codesnippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious "writing to template.html" twice, you are not sending the contents of $download in the **get.php** file. Place

```
echo $download;
```

as the last line of get.php.

Comment: Indeed, you were right - a stupid mistake. It works, thanks dude. :D

Answer (score 0):

write down your `html` code before `php` code so its work

```
<form method="post" action="get.php">
<div id="container">
<input type="submit" id="download" value="Download template"/>
</div>
</form>
```

and after that code add your `file write` code because

`ob_get_flush()` Returns the output buffer or FALSE if no buffering is active. and your buffer empty so its return `false`